# Does GitHub offer a standardized way/recipe for downloading maven artifacts within a GitHub Actions build?

Tags: docker, maven, github-actions, artifactory

In a Github Actions build, I was hoping that GitHub/Maven would offer a recipe or somewhat standardized template for how to download artifacts from a locally hosted Maven Repository.  I have my own runner, and so far I've only seen open source Actions for generating a settings.xml file for Maven.  I'd like to be able to store the user/pass in GitHub Secrets for the action.  With this, are there alternatives to generating the settings.xml via the GitHub Action for downloading maven dependencies for the docker build, or is that the only approach for accessing the secret from GitHub secrets and using it for Maven access?

I've tried looking through open source solutions, and found a few options that could be used, but I wanted to identify if there were any other standardized ways for handling this since it seems like it would be a pretty standard problem in GitHub actions docker builds.

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/actions.

Comment: Probably more of a maven configuration question than a GitHub Actions question. Your project (e.g., the `pom.xml`) needs to be configured to access your locally hosted repository and, for example, pull credentials from environment variables. Once your maven project is configured correctly to retrieve auth via env variables, you can just set those necessary variables in your workflow with `${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}`. I would expect the action you use simply to run something like `mvn install`.